# On a Blackberry, How do you schedule your app to come on at a specific time?

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile, scheduling

The context for my question is that of an alarm application but I would like to know in the general case. How do you schedule your application to turn on at a point in time in the future? For instance, if I set an alarm to play a noise tomorrow at 8:00 am how do I make this happen if the device has closed my app?

*editted to correct spelling/punctuation.

Comment: Why was my question down voted? If you are going to down vote arbitrarily at least leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: +1 this is a good and valid programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ApplicationManager.scheduleApplication()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#scheduleApplication%28net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor,%20long,%20boolean%29)